# How to verify if check box is checked or not by JavascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have problem to check if checkbox is checked or not using JavascriptExecutor

```
VatisChecked = (boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].checked", TaxCheckMark);
```

I tried the code above, but it the return gives me null "VatisChecked" is a Boolean String and "TaxCheckMark" is Element location

```
<label class="checkbox checked" ng-class="{checked:$Gadget.vatTaxChecked}">
                                    <ins id="restrictAccess" class="uIcon"></ins>
                                </label>
```

I just want to know how if checkBox is checked or not using JavascriptExecutor and above code to return true or false.

Comment: Any reason why you would use a _JavascriptExecutor_ instead of the pure _Java_ methods?

Comment: i tried isSelected() method but is not working always return false also for another case to make check on checkbox normal behavior not working only JavascriptExecutor worked

Comment: It's obvious that `isSelected()` method not worked as the element is not a checkbox, it's a label. You have to get_attribute `class` and then check if class contains `checked`. I am sure the class `checked` will not displayed if the label is not selected.

Comment: unfortunately the class include checked even if label not selected and here below when element is not selected  
    <label class="checkbox" ng-class="{checked:$Gadget.vatTaxChecked}">
          <ins id="restrictAccess" class="uIcon"></ins>
         </label>